# ArcGIS Server - problem publishing python script that uses urllib

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server

I have problem publishing this simple python script as geoprocessing service with ArcGIS Server.

```
import urllib
import arcpy

u = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
url = "http://geoegl.msp.gouv.qc.ca/cgi-wms/mapcache.fcgi/tms/1.0.0/carte_gouv_qc_public@EPSG_3857/" + u

image = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

arcpy.SetParameter(1,image)
```

This is a simple proxy that uses urllib to redirect images. When I try to publish this script, ArcMap always go idle for a long long time. I think the cause of the problem is `urllib`. If I try to publish a script that do not import `urllib`, I have no problem.

After a long idle time, the Publisher returns the following errors:

```
High    Unresolved    00178    Data: C:\Windows\bfsvc.exe, used by Script Script cannot be copied to the server

High    Unresolved    24032    Data source used by Script Script is not registered with the server and will be copied to the server: C:\temp\arcgis\arcpy\
```

Can someone tell me why trying to publish a python script that import `urllib` into ArcGIS Server could return those errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the following post:

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/158172

It looks like if you change your import from:

```
import urllib
```

to:

```
from urllib import *
```

this may resolve your problem.

Comment: Wow that's correct! Do you have an idea what was the problem?

Comment: Are you able to get to the REST endpoint for the service, or does that fail as well?  If so, does it error out when you try to run it via the REST endpoint?

Comment: The REST endpoint works and I can use the service, however I cant manage its settings in the Admin console because of some javascript errors

Comment: Try using an administrative ArcGIS Server connection in ArcCatalog to manage settings for the service.  Also, not sure what the main cause is of the import problem.  My guess is that the process for the server that reviews the python misinterprets the imports as data.  What version of ArcGIS Server are you using?

Comment: We are using ArcGIS Server 10.3